pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: The DNS query name does not exist: _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.mongodb.net
I am trying to run my flask application with mongoDB. I have added config file of mongodb to connect with it. I end up getting an error message when I try to run the application.
This is my config.py
import os
class Config:
    MONGO_URI = os.getenv('MONGO_URI', 'mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.hcccttb.mongodb.net/<database-name>')
    JWT_SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('JWT_SECRET', '123456.')


You can refer to my full code
I try to run my flask application with mongoDB and getting the error:
pymongo.errors.ConfigurationError: The DNS query name does not exist: _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.mongodb.net.


Odd that the hostname in the error message is different from the host in the connection string
